# Do I have to pay higher cost or same domain renewal price when my domain gets popular?

Tags: domain, hosting, domain-name

Assume that I have purchased a domain from Godaddy. At the purchase time they state the renewal price as $14.99/yr. If my site get lot of traffic and domain becomes popular, will they increase the domain renewal cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Registrars do not change the standard registration price in relation to the domain name's popularity.  (If they do, you can move to another.)

It's your domain till you decide to sell it (for whatever price you set/negotiate), or it's registration expires, then it's up for grabs.

Some registrars own domains or broker the sale of domains.  However, the sale price should have no effect on regular registration price.

Comment: Would be important to note that some registrar do not take a domain name in your name, some of them will register the domain name so you can use it, but enter their information in the WhoIs and make themself the owner. I've seen it happen multiple times to my customers before they switch for me or for another domain reseller.

Comment: @TheBird956, really can you give name(s) of such registrars to avoid?  I've seen registration with **whois privacy** that registers a domain (public record) using the registrar's details, but that's something you choose, and a registrar would not risk losing their business/certification by stealing domains in such cases.

Comment: GoDaddy is a provider I do not recomment. They give a good service and they are good for it, but when you want to switch to another service provider it can be a real problem. I cannot name any providers my customers has been with because that kind of information is private, but from my personnal experience, do not go with BitronicTech. They changed management and I almost had to call a lawyer to get my domains back. They were great before, but its not the case anymore.

Comment: As a general ruel, privacy protection for domain is the kind of thing you need a lot of trust. Only trust big companies for that, since they have a reputation to keep. In the case of smaller companies, see if they are going through another big company to give privacy protection. If they do their own, in-house privacy protection, be carefull. What privacy protection is, is simply editing the information to other legal information and forward everything to the real owner when necessary (email forwarding and such).

Comment: Which provider do you recommend then @TheBird956?